# Handling a Connection timed out: connect java

Tags: java

what is the best way to handle a Connection timed out: connect error ?

i am currently getting this error in the console :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at Webcrallertesting.crawler(Webcrallertesting.java:140)
    at Webcrallertesting.main(Webcrallertesting.java:53)
Java Result: 1
```

this is the code :

```
                HttpURLConnection conn;
                BufferedReader rd;
                String line;
                String result = "";
                System.out.println(urlString.getClass());
//                url = new URL(urlString);
                String url = urlString;
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int code = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(code);
                if (code == 200) {
                    try {
                        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                            result += line;
                            rd.close();
                            System.out.println(result);//                try {
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Did not get a 200 response");
                }
```

what i am trying  to achieve is when i get the time out connect error, it either retries, or ignores this handles it and restarts the connection ? either way i need it not to crash the console

what is the best method for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using exception do whatever you want, like adding a retry mechanism or ignore etc..

```
try {

                    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                        rd.close();
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    retry();
                }
```

it's better if you catch java.net.ConnectException instead of just Exception to avoid any mistakes